# I 'd like to change image file when editing the post using carrierwave on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave

I added image-uploading function with carrierwave and Imagemagick.
It works when writing a new post, but when I edit the post and try changing to another image file, it doesn't work. It still has the images I uploaded first time even though I edited the 'edit_complete' action in controller.

This is part of the post table's migration file.

```
class CreateHospitalReviews < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  t.string :image1
  t.string :image2
  t.text :content
 end
end
```

This is part of the post table's model file.

```
class HospitalReview < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image1, ImageUploader
  mount_uploader :image2, ImageUploader
end
```

This is part of 'write.html.erb'(view of writing a new post.)

```
<p>Upload imagefile: </p>
<p><input type="file" name="image1"></p>
<p><input type="file" name="image2"></p>
```

This is part of 'edit.html.erb'(view of editing written post.)

```
<p>Upload imagefile: </p>
<p><input type="file" name="image1" value="<%=@post.image1%>"></p>
<p><input type="file" name="image2" value="<%=@post.image2%>"></p>
```

This is part of edit_post action in controller.

```
def edit_complete
 review = HospitalReview.find(params[:id])
 review.image1 = params[:image1]
 review.image2 = params[:image2]
 review.save
end
```

I can't find what's wrong with the MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Remove value attribute from file inputs.

To display image on edit page use html **img** tag and provide path of the image to **src** attribute of img tag.

Comment: I removed the value attribute from 'edit.html.erb' and  added <p><img style="margin-right:20px" src="<%= @post.image1_url(:medium) %>"><img src="<%= @post.image2_url(:medium) %>"></p> in 'show.html.erb', which  shows the post detailed, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Update edit method as :
   review = HospitalReview.find(params[:id])
   review.update_attributes(:image1 => params[:image1], :image2 => params[:image2])